# How to execute kubernetes job with ansible module

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook to run a k8s job with ansible, but I have timeout problems.

Ansible 2.8.1
Kubernetes 1.11

```
  tasks:
  - name: Execute1
    k8s_raw:
      state: present
      host: api-br-k8s-k8s-XXXXXX-001100.sa-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
      verify_ssl: no
      username: username
      password: "password"
      definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'files/job.yml')| from_yaml }}"
```

The job.yml is ok, I'm tested with `kubectl -f job.yaml apply`.
The Host, User and Pass is ok, I'm tested in browser.

I expect the output is the creation of a job from the .yml file

Comment: I solved this with an ansible module shell, because searching I found several people with the same problem with this module of kubernetes. 

This with other steps:

```- name: Container Exec 3 - Verify Job and Exec Job
  shell: docker exec job-backup-portal bash -c 'VERIFY_JOB=$(kubectl -n production get job| grep -c backup-portal-site); [[ ${VERIFY_JOB} -ge 1 ]] && kubectl -n production delete job backup-portal-site || kubectl -n production -f /home/job.yml apply'```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vinicius Peres mentioned in the comment, the issue has been solved by applying command lines within Ansible [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module, deserving the same result as was expected to get from playbook through [k8s_raw](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/k8s_raw_module.html) module.

```
- name: Container Exec 3 - Verify Job and Exec Job
  shell: docker exec job-backup-portal bash -c 'VERIFY_JOB=$(kubectl -n production get job| grep -c backup-portal-site); [[ ${VERIFY_JOB} -ge 1 ]] && kubectl -n production delete job backup-portal-site || kubectl -n production -f /home/job.yml apply'
```

Match `wiki` flag to this answer as potential workaround solution.

Comment: Not sure whether the module is broken or there is something wrong in your cluster. However, this should not be used for further contributors research, but rather be seen as a work-around. The ansible way-to-go would be by using the module... and also, instead of placing `&&` in your one shell line, you could split it up, register each command and debug it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @Kevin, thank you very much for your help and observation.

Comment: why are u running docker command when the question asks about k8s?